# How to duplicate a master page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I'm trying to skin a 3rd party asp.net application and don't boast to have any knowledge with MS web technologies.

One page design has a considerably different underlying html structure that can't be achieved with pure css so I need a new master file for this page.

I've naively duplicated a file called `Main.Master` renamed it `Login.Master` and changed the reference in the Page file that extends Main.Master to Extend the new master page file, **e.g:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Login.Master" EnableViewState="true" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="xxx.login" 
    Culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" UICulture="auto" %>
```

In Login Master I've not changed a thing, as all the logic should be identical, I just want to change the structure of the HTML.

With the small change mentioned above I get several parser errors along the lines of:

```
Parser Error Message: The resource object with key 'somekey' was not found.
```

When I delete the reference to said error, it causes a new parser error further down, and so on and so forth.

I've also tried not having a master page for the page in question but that throws up a whole new collection of errors.

To make things worse, it's on a remote server and I don't have access to visual studio so would prefer a solution that wouldn't require compilation if at all possible.

Comment: Have you checked the code behind file for appropriate changes, like the actual class name? Are you sure the class name is `xxx.login`?

Comment: Nothing in that regard has changed. I've duplicated Main.Master, renamed it and changed the page which initially used Main.Master to use the identical Duplicate Login.Master. None of the code behind has changed yet Main.Master works and the identical but renamed file doesnt

Comment: Well then please check if to see if the class name in the code behind was changed when you renamed it or not.